# What is the Python equivalent to Django File object?

Tags: python, django, phantomjs

I need to modify the HTTP header of a file within Python, and I know this is possible using the Django 'File' object (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/) as documented in the example I'm following here: http://tmanstwobits.com/convert-your-web-pages-to-pdf-files-using-phantomjs.html

Here's the basic code I'm trying to duplicate without Django:

```
file_name = '/tmp/current_page.pdf'
url = ('user_current_url')
external_process = Popen(["phantomjs", phantomjs_script, url, file_name],
                         stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
# Open the file created by PhantomJS
return_file = File(open(file_name, 'r'))
response = HttpResponse(return_file, mimetype='application/force-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=current_page.pdf'
# Return the file to the browser and force it as download item
return response
```

I've tried using urllib.urlopen, which allows me to modify the HTTP header, but I run into other problems and it doesn't seem like the best approach. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You're getting a framework for server side HTTP (Django) and a HTTP client library (urllib) confused. What exactly is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @LukasGraf I'm trying to use PhantomJS to create a PDF of one of my HTML templates, then send that PDF to the client when they click on a 'download PDF' button while viewing the page.

Comment: @JamesGentes: How are you sending it?

Comment: @Blender if you're referring to how I'm sending the file to the client, I haven't figured that out yet. That's why I'm trying to modify the header of the file to include 'Content-Disposition: attachment;'

Comment: @JamesGentes: What environment is this running under? WSGI? CGI? How are you trying to send the file now?

Comment: @Blender it's Tornado, not WSGI I don't think. I have tried just 'returning' the file, but that didn't work and I figured I needed an http response with the 'attachment' instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Tornado, you have to setup a request handler:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class PDFHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        filename = 'current_page.pdf'

        self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=current_page.pdf')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/force-download')

        with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
            data = handle.read()
            self.set_header('Content-Length', len(data))
            self.write(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', PDFHandler),
    ])

    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I would use the `tempfile` module instead of hard-coding the paths. Also, streaming the file in chunks would be good if you're concerned about memory usage.

Comment: Thanks @Blender, that works great if I use a GET for the page, however I have to send some url arguments (the page to convert to PDF) using POST (unless there's a way to send them via GET that I don't know of). I added your code and tried to use self.get() at the end of my POST, but that didn't work. Any ideas for how the client would use POST to send arguments, then send the PDF back using the requesthandler method you described?

Comment: ah, just figured out how to get my arguments using a GET, so I'm good to go :)

Comment: @JamesGentes: I've never tried Tornado before. It looks pretty cool. Thanks for showing it to me.